# Is there any way to change the password of the current user account using the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, passwords, user-accounts

Are there any commands for the Windows command line which allows you to change the password of the account?  What about *without* using the current password?

(I saw a video about it once and it worked but over time I forgot it...)

Comment: Why does this question have 1k views again?

Comment: because of the misleading title. could have been "free porn" and it would have 10k views :)

Comment: True. Question is, how many of those are coming from Google and how many are Super Users? Seems to happen with a lot of Mac questions, too (well, probably for different reasons).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The Solution which Breakthrough gave is useless if you have a limited account.Here's what you to get admin privileges :-

Step One:
First, open Command Prompt
(either; Start->Run->Type cmd.exe->OK OR; Double-Click C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

Step Two:
Create an account, if you do not wish to create a new account, ignore this step.
Type the following into the black box that appears (command prompt)

net user   /add

Example:
net user max 123456 /add

This will create a password protected account.
The username will be max
The password will be 123456

Step Three:
Find all of the user groups that are available on the network

net localgroup

This will bring up a list like this
*Administrators
*Debugger Users
*Guests
*HelpServicesGroup
*Users
The command completed successfully. (can be different according to different systems)

Step Four:
Input the following into Command Prompt

net localgroup   /add

Example:

net localgroup administrators max /add

This would add the username “max” join the group “administrators” and have all privileges related to that group.

This will work on local machines. and if you are lucky enough and the admin is not very good on what he is doing you can create your own admin account in an networked environment as well :) :) but if the cmd command prompt is restricted or a manual access rights are placed then no way to make this work.. You will probably get into trouble if you get caught doing this.. I have only provided this as an example of what you can do with command prompt and thus why it should always be disabled on limited accounts, I am not responsible for anything you do with this. also note that this only work at home or in an unmanaged network.

Have fun

Comment: you don't seem to be asking the question which was asked, and your solution suffers from the problem of being "on the other side of this locked door"

Comment: If you're a limited user, you can't create new accounts, nor can you add groups (much less Administrators) to an existing account.  Windows account security would be useless if non-privileged accounts could create privileged accounts at will.  Using the command prompt doesn't bypass these restrictions.

Answer (score 17):

```
net user [USERNAME] *
```

Just replace [USERNAME] with yours, and hit enter.  It will prompt you for the new password.  If you have trimmed your Windows installation, however, the program may not be available (this usually only occurs if you use nLite/vLite/RT7Lite and removed something you shouldn't have).

Comment: add /domain if it's a domain account

Comment: Just an FYI: I believe you need to be a local/domain admin for it to work without knowing the old password. At least that is how the Win32 API works (which I imagine is what net.exe will call).

Comment: This is an answer to a different question. It does not change the _current user's_ password. It changes the password of the _specified user_. The difference is important, because the specified user may not have the privileges necessary to change other people's passwords -- and Windows is too dumb to realize, he is changing _his own_ and thus should be allowed even if otherwise unprivileged.